# Select applied to multiple objects

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I have a matrix and want to extract rows according to some criterion.  Then I have other matrices and want to extract the same rows.  For example, if my criterion is to find rows where all the elements are smaller than some number, I can write

```
m = Table[i j/10., {i, 5}, {j, 3}]
```

which returns

```
{
 {0.1, 0.2, 0.3},
 {0.2, 0.4, 0.6},
 {0.3, 0.6, 0.9},
 {0.4, 0.8, 1.2},
 {0.5, 1., 1.5}
}
```

Then

```
Select[m, Max[#] < 1. &]
```

selects the first three rows of `m`.  Alternatively,

```
m[[{1, 2, 3}, All]]
```

also extracts the same first three rows.  So if I had the list `{1,2,3}`, I could use that list to extract the corresponding rows from any number of other objects.  To find the list, I tried

```
Position[m, Max[#] < 1. &]
```

but it returns the empty list.  Why doesn't this work?  Is there a better approach?  Also, for my real application, execution speed is potentially important.

Update:  I am impressed at how many different ways to do this exist!  I was also interested in how fast the approaches run.  I ran a test on a slightly different task (closer to my application, although my initial list isn't random!).

```
m = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 20}];
lst1 = Position[(Max[Abs[#]] < 0.9) & /@ m, True] // Flatten // 
   AbsoluteTiming;
lst2 = ResourceFunction["SelectIndices"][m, (Max[Abs[#]] < 0.9) &] // 
    Flatten // AbsoluteTiming;
lst3 = Flatten@
    Position[
     Flatten[ResourceFunction[
         "ThroughOperator"][{(Max[Abs[#]] < 0.9) &}] /@ m], True] // 
   AbsoluteTiming;
lst4 = ResourceFunction["SelectPositions"][m, (Max[Abs[#]] < 0.9) &] //
    Flatten // AbsoluteTiming; 
lst5 = 
 Position[m, _?(AllTrue[(Max[Abs[#]] < 0.9) &]), {1}, 
   Heads -> False] // AbsoluteTiming;
lst6 = Flatten[
    Table[Position[m, Select[AllTrue[# < 1 &]][m][[i]]], {i, 1, 
      Length@Select[AllTrue[(Max[Abs[#]] < 0.9) &]][m]}]] // 
   AbsoluteTiming;
{lst1[[1]], lst2[[1]], lst3[[1]], lst4[[1]], lst5[[1]], lst6[[1]]}
```

returns

```
{0.002089, 0.002717, 0.003723, 0.007242, 0.009424, 1.09962}
```

Sorry for obsessing, but here's a new winner (replaces anon. function with explicit one):

```
(Position[LessThan[0.9] /@ (Max /@ Abs[m]), True] // Flatten // 
   AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
```

returns 0.001294.  By the way, if the number of rows is smaller than 1000, the ordering of which is fastest changes.  (Try 100 and 10.)  But method 1 and this variant seem always to be the fastest.

Comment: Might want to use `ResourceFunction["SelectPositions"]` or `ResourceFunction["SelectIndices"]` to get the locations of interest, then use those in `Part` or `Extract`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
lst = Position[(Max[#]<1)&/@m,True]

(* {{1}, {2}, {3}} *)
```

Using [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html)

```
 Extract[m,lst]
 (* {
     {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, 
     {0.2, 0.4, 0.6}, 
     {0.3, 0.6, 0.9}
    } *)
```

Using [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

```
 m[[Flatten@lst]]

(* {
     {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, 
     {0.2, 0.4, 0.6}, 
     {0.3, 0.6, 0.9}
    } *)
```

And:

```
m//#[[Flatten@Position[(Max[#]<1)&/@m,False]]]&

(* {
    {0.4, 0.8, 1.2}, 
    {0.5, 1., 1.5}
   } *)
```

Comment: This was the most useful to me (and runs very fast).  Thanks!  It's also a good reminder to me to look at the Function Repository.   I will check out those other functions, too.

Answer (score 8):

My suggested solution is based on

> So if I had the list `{1,2,3}`, I could use that list to extract the corresponding rows from any number of other objects. To find the list, I tried I tried `Position[m, Max[#] < 1. &]` but it returns the empty list.

I will borrow something from @Syed's answer. Observe that while

```
Position[m, Select[AllTrue[# < 1 &]][m]]
```

does not give you anything, the following

```
Position[m, Select[AllTrue[# < 1 &]][m][[1]]]
```

gives

> [image: 1]

Wrap a nice `Table` around it and `Flatten` it

```
Flatten[Table[
  Position[m, Select[AllTrue[# < 1 &]][m][[i]]], {i, 1, 
   Length@Select[AllTrue[# < 1 &]][m]}]]
```

> [image: 123]

**Edit** another way to get the `{1,2,3}` is to use the resource function called [**`ThroughOperator`**](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ThroughOperator/) that can do that. This is a development thanks to @Sjoerd Smit.

```
Flatten@Position[
  Flatten[ResourceFunction["ThroughOperator"][{Max[#] < 1 &}] /@ m], 
  True]
```

> [image: 123]

Answer (score 7):

**Using `Select`:**

```
m = Table[i j/10., {i, 5}, {j, 3}]
Select[AllTrue[# < 1 &]][m]
```

**Using `Pick`:**

Define a helper function:

```
f[k_List] := Max[k] < 1
Pick[m, f /@ m]
```

**Using `DeleteCases`:**

```
DeleteCases[m, _?(AnyTrue[# > 1 &])]
```

**Using `Position/Extract`:**

As `Position` expects a pattern:

```
pos = Position[m, _?(Max@# < 1 &), {1}]
```

OR

```
pos = Position[m, _?(AllTrue[# < 1 &]), {1}, Heads -> False]
```

give you the positions that you can extract values from other matrices; e.g.,

```
Extract[m, pos]
```

---

Result:

> {{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.9}}

Comment: The only issue here is that, without an index (such as lst), I do not see how to extract the columns from multiple matrices.  If I had only one matrix to extract from, these would be fine.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't read the question carefully enough, it seems. I have updated the answer that uses a pattern for extracting the said positions..

Answer (score 4):

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[m, Max@# < 1 &], True]
(*{{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6}, {0.3, 0.6, 0.9}}*)
Lookup[GroupBy[m, Max@# < 1 &], False]
(*{{0.4, 0.8, 1.2}, {0.5, 1., 1.5}}*)
```